# how to i add/remove photos in the ios 10 movie feature

Tags: ios, photos.app

not sure how iOS 10 chooses the images for its People movies, but i'd like to add/subtract some.  anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

How to edit your title, music, duration, and photos in a Memories slideshow

**Launch the Photos app from your home screen.**

1. Tap Memories in the menu bar at the bottom of the screen. It looks
   like a triangle with an arrow circling it.
2. Tap the memory you would like to see.
3. Launch the photos app from your home screen, tap Memories and the
   select the memory you would like to see.
   [image]
4. Tap the play button on the large photo at the top of the screen.
5. Tap the screen anywhere.
6. Tap the pause button that appears at the bottom of the screen.

[image]

7. Tap the editing menu in the lower right corner.
8. Tap on title, music, duration, or photos & videos to adjust your
   settings.
9. Tap Done when you are happy with your settings.

[image]